# Bootstrap - How do I get a responsive nav bar that outputs a Menu button and drops your lists down when you resize your browser?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a nav bar that automatically turns into a Menu button and collapses when you minimize your browser
I want it to be exactly like this one http://php1.emagid.net/~laurenbe/
I looked up tutorials but every tutorial only teaches us how to do the bar static to the top of the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0amcs6L7/) It's the menu you wanted but it's up to you to figure out the rest.

Comment: omg that looks like what I exactly want. Do I have to include the JS you wrote? Or just the HTML and CSS? I'm using Bootstrap

Comment: That is the exact menu. I pulled the code from the website you used as an example, but I didn't do all of the work, which is why I didn't post it as an answer. The JS is for making the menu button appear. The CSS is for the styling. The HTML still has the unneccessary classes from the wordpress install on it so you will have to do a little work to get it up and running. But as @JonKyte answered, a toggable menu is built into bootstrap and you can override the css to make it look like the one in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of bootstrap, the [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

At it's most basic, you want to do this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <div class="btn btn-primary">Menu</div>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

You can then use custom CSS styles to over-ride bootstraps native styling.

Comment: Thank you that looks like something closer to what I am aiming for. I just need to learn the syntax.. But I'm so frustrated at myself right now for being a beginner at this

Comment: The bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/) are invaluable when you aren't familiar with bootstraps methods. You can achieve exactly the result you are looking for with their Navbar code ^. You can vote my answer up or mark it as correct if it helped or solved your question. @jaegerbomb91

Comment: Thanks, yours isn't really what I'm looking for , but it's closer than what I've seen on the getbootstrap docs. I can't vote you up yet cause I don't have 15 reps lol. My Menu button isn't centerized, do you know how to  fix it?

Comment: Display your button as an inline-block and add `text-align: center;` to the parent. @jaegerbomb91

Comment: When you want to make changes in your bootstrap design, do you modify your style.css or their bootstrap.min.css ?

Comment: You can modify your `style.css` to overwrite their styles, or modify `bootstrap.css` (or `bootstrap.min.css` which would be difficult to read if it's minified - you should edit the un-minified version, and then minify it for production). It would be better for perf to modify bootstrap.css instead of writing more CSS just to overwrite the existing bootstrap styles. Hope that makes sense. @jaegerbomb91

Answer (score 1):

It's all about responsive design, so you can have help here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

Here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/

And a beginner video for bootstrap if you're not familiar with it : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=no-Ntkc836w